# Recommended column delimiter for Click stream data to consumed by SSIS

Tags: url, ssis, data-export

I am working with some click stream data and i would need to give specifications to the vendor regarding a preferred format to be consumed by SSIS.

As its URL data in the text file which column delimiter would you recommend. I was thinking pipe "|" but i realize that pipes can be used within the URL.

I did some testing to specify multiple charecters as delimiter lile |^| but when I am creating a flat file connection there is not option in SSIS. I had type these charecters. But when i went to edit the flat file connection manager it had changed to {|}^{|}. It just made me nervous to the import succeeded.

I just wanted to see if anybody has good ideas as to which would safe column delimiter to use.

Answer (score 1):

Probably tab-delimited would be fairly safe, at least assuming that by "clickstream" you mean a list of URLs or something similar. But in theory any delimiter should be fine as long as the supplier [quotes the data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) appropriately.